# How to access specific websites automatically through a proxy server in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I have free access to academic literature through the library system of my institution. Let me briefly describe my current workflow.

1. I access a restricted academic article, such as [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195666315002123) one on ScienceDirect.
2. I use a bookmarklet with this code: `javascript:void(location.href='https://login.proxy.library.uu.nl/login?auth=eng&url='+location.href)`
3. This redirects the URL of the article to the proxy login site of my institution.
4. I enter my credentials to be forwarded back to `http://www.sciencedirect.com.proxy.library.uu.nl/science/article/pii/S0195666315002123` where I get free access to the article.

With Google Chrome, is there any way to automatise the above process so that for certain pages (such as ScienceDirect), Chrome automatically uses the proxy URL with my stored credentials?

Comment: Does this work? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ezproxy/ednonnjhnmhbmockcgihebokfcifboad?hl=en

Comment: Hello @Sathya, this extension acts similarly to the bookmarklet in that it redirects me to my proxy login page on click of the button in Chrome's top right extension icon bar. However, it does not forward or login me automatically with my credentials.

Comment: Wonder if you can try using [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/)' autofill for auto login along with your bookmarklet or this extension?

Comment: I ticked the auto-login option in Lastpass but it doesn't fill them automatically.